# AngularJS UI router $onLocationChangeStart event.PreventDefault does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need a way to interrupt a user navigating to a new page when there are unsaved changes on the current page. I implemented a modified version of the solution here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs-controllers

However, what I see in the browser is that as soon as the user clicks on a link, the view changes and the new controller *loads completely* while the modal dialog is displayed. When the user clicks 'cancel' and event.preventDefault is fired, the user simply ends up on the new view. This is strange because everything I've read indicates that this is the accepted method, and nobody seems to have this issue. Yet I can't for the life of me see what is wrong with my code.

Here's the function in the main app for handling location changes (ModalService just wraps the angular bootstrap $modal service):

```
    onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);

    function routeChange(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
        //Navigate to newUrl if the form isn't dirty
        if (!$rootScope.unsavedChanges) return;

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
            actionButtonText: 'Ignore Changes',
            headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
            bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Leave the page?'
        };

        ModalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).result.then(function () {
                $rootScope.unsavedChanges = false;
                $location.path(newUrl); //Go to page they're interested in
            }
        , function () {
            event.preventDefault();
        });         
        return;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: prevent default before opening modal

Comment: That doesn't help I'm afraid. The new controller/view has loaded before the modal opens, and regardless of whether I call event.preventDefault.

Comment: This function is called at the start of the change only before view change. Just try with only event.preventDafault inside the route change function to check if it just restricts the change in url. Then you can check if something other is wrong in the function.

Comment: Having the same problem. Was directed to look at this link...that it could possibly provide a workaround: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5581

Comment: @Kop4Lyf: Tried it, but no luck. I can clearly see that the view has already changed when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Can you create a small fiddle with just the route changes and this event?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else has this problem, the fix turned out to be quite simple. I moved the code to the stateChangeStart event. Code looks like this:

```
    onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', routeChange);

    function routeChange(event, newState) {
        //Navigate to newUrl if the form isn't dirty
        if (!$rootScope.unsavedChanges) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
            actionButtonText: 'Ignore Changes',
            headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
            bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Leave the page?'
        };

        ModalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).result.then(function () {
            $rootScope.unsavedChanges = false;
            $state.go(newState); //Go to page they're interested in
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the share man, works perfect. However i am thinking what about  state params.